# Go to another page and scroll to a specific div on one click (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My question is simple but I don't know what to do, I'm working on a website using Reactjs and here's my issue
I need to scroll down to a specific div on button click, it works fine when I'm on the same page but when I'm on a different page it navigates only (as the button is in the nav bar so it appears in all the pages).

I'm using react-scroll's link and here's the code:

```
import { Link as Scrolllink, animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll'

                <li className="has-children" >
                    <Scrolllink
                        onClick={() => props.history.push('/fashion')}
                        to="HowItWorks"
                        spy={true}
                        smooth={true}
                        offset={-70}
                        duration={1500}
                    >How it works</Scrolllink>
                </li>
```

So What should I do to make it navigate then scroll?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried add an id to that div and  append #div-id to your url? `/fashion#div-id-to-scroll`

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo yes, got the same issue, I have to click again to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You may be encountering a case where because the click on the scroll link isn't cancelled, it'll do a full page load of the href on the link rather than just doing a single-page navigation. Change your onClick to:

```
onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.history.push('/fashion');
}}
```